# how do i get the last element of a $.each

Tags: jquery

i have this

```
     $.each(data, function (url) {
      $("ul").append($("<li class='horizontal'></li>").html(this.title));
    });
```

I want to add the class last to the last one...how would i do that

Comment: I'm assuming there is only 1 ul, and you want to add the class 'horizonal' to the last li?  You should really explain that in the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$.each(data, function(i,v){
  $('<li />').html(v.title).appendTo('ul');
});
$('ul li:last').addClass('horizontal');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWhf5/1/)

Comment: I also improved your loop, use `appendTo` instead of putting a jQuery object inside `append`.

Comment: As another tiny point (not nitpicking), `$("<li></li>")` can just be `$("<li />")`.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean to the UL or LI? Just do (after the loop):

```
$("#theUl li:last").addClass("horizontal"); // or $("ul:last"), whichever you mean
```

You can do it within the loop, but I would not suggest it, as it will require a check at each iteration.

For better overall performance, you can reduce the number of writes to the DOM by building up the LIs *offline* and appending them in one go:

```
var lis = '';
$.each(data, function (url) {
    lis += "<li>" + this.title + "</li>";
});
$("ul").append(lis);
$("ul li:last").addClass("horizontal");
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `lis += "<li>" + this.title + "</li>";`  Only the last li has the 'horizontal' class.

Answer (score 1):

If data is an array, you could do

```
data.length
```

and it'll give you the quantity. Then, one could carry a counter inside the .each and check if you got to the last element.

Something like that... but there should be a last selector in jquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.each(data, function (url) {
  $("ul").append($("<li class='horizontal'></li>").html(this.title));
});

$("ul li:last").addClass("last");
```